# Converting Json string date into ZoneDateTime in Spring 4 MVC

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I am able to get ZoneDateTime from calling spring rest api. The date that I get in json is in following format:

```
{
    "2017-04-24T15:13:06-05:00"
}
```

I was able to achieve this in Spring 4 MVC by configuring the following code in ApplicationConfiguration.class:

```
@Override
     public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL); 

            objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

            objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()); 

            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(); 
            converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper); 

            converters.add(converter); 
        }
```

Now, when i want to send that json date to spring rest for post operation. I am getting following exception:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.time.ZonedDateTime from String value ("2017-04-24T15:13:06-05:00"): Text '2017-04-24T15:13:06-05:00' could not be parsed at index 19
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.time.ZonedDateTime from String value ("2017-04-24T15:13:06-05:00"): Text '2017-04-24T15:13:06-05:00' could not be parsed at index 19
```

I tried using CustomDeserialization.class and annotating the ZoneDateTime field with @JsonDeserialize(CustomDeserialization.class) but this is also not working.

What is the best way for converting json having date into ZoneDateTime in Spring 4 MVC?

Comment: What should be the zone in the first place? There are multiple time zones having a -05:00 offset. Which one should be chosen? Why do you want to deserialize something that doesn't look like a zoned date time to a zoned date time?

Comment: I have one createdDate field in entity class which is stored as ZoneDateTime in database. I just wanted to send json string of ZoneDateTime and store that in database. By using ObjectMapper I was able to get ZoneDateTime from database but not able to send using post request.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send a date using JSON, I believe that the simplest way is to first convert the Date into Long type and only then send it as JSON. Something like this:

```
public class MyJson {

    Long date;

    public MyJson() {

    }

    public MyJson(Long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Long getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

and on main method:

```
    Date date = new Date();
    MyJson json = new MyJson(date.getTime());

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();     
    String strJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(json);

    MyJson result = objectMapper.readValue(strJson, MyJson.class);
```